# Using external api data in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a search engine with some filters in react using redux. To do this, I need help to replace the data declared below by an external API

I'm not yet comfortable with react and redux. I'd like to pass data from an API to the filters declared at the bottom. To do this, I need to replace the data at the top with the link from my API.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    latestJob: [],
    category: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Residential",
            value: "residential",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Commercial",
            value: "commercial",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Industrial",
            value: "industrial",
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: "Apartments",
            value: "apartments",
        },
    ],
    jobTypeList: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Freelancer",
            value: "freelancer",
            isChecked: false,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Full Time",
            value: "full-time",
            isChecked: false,
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Part Time",
            value: "part-time",
            isChecked: false,
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: "Temporary",
            value: "temporary",
            isChecked: false,
        },
    ],
    datePost: [
        { id: 1, name: "All", value: "all", isChecked: false },
        { id: 2, name: "Last Hour", value: "last-hour", isChecked: false },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Last 24 Hour",
            value: "last-24-hour",
            isChecked: false,
        },
        { id: 4, name: "Last 7 Days", value: "last-7-days", isChecked: false },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "Last 14 Days",
            value: "last-14-days",
            isChecked: false,
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            name: "Last 30 Days",
            value: "last-30-days",
            isChecked: false,
        },
    ],
    experienceLavel: [
        { id: 1, name: "Fresh", value: "fresh", isChecked: false },
        { id: 2, name: "1 Year", value: "1-year", isChecked: false },
        { id: 3, name: "2 Year", value: "2-year", isChecked: false },
        { id: 4, name: "3 Year", value: "3-year", isChecked: false },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "4 Year",
            value: "4-year",
            isChecked: false,
        },
    ],
    tags: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "App",
            value: "app",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Administrative",
            value: "administrative",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Android",
            value: "android",
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: "Wordpress",
            value: "wordpress",
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "Design",
            value: "design",
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            name: "React",
            value: "react",
        },
    ],
};
```

```
export const jobSlice = createSlice({
    name: "job",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addLatestJob: (state, { payload }) => {
            const isExist = state.latestJob?.includes(payload);
            if (isExist) {
                state.latestJob = state.latestJob.filter(
                    (item) => item !== payload
                );
            } else {
                state.latestJob.push(payload);
            }
        },
        clearJobTypeToggle: (state) => {
            state?.jobTypeList?.map((item) => {
                item.isChecked = false;
                return {
                    ...item,
                };
            });
        },
        jobTypeCheck: (state, { payload }) => {
            state?.jobTypeList?.map((item) => {
                if (item.id === payload) {
                    if (item.isChecked) {
                        item.isChecked = false;
                    } else {
                        item.isChecked = true;
                    }
                }
                return {
                    ...item,
                };
            });
        },
        datePostCheck: (state, { payload }) => {
            state?.datePost?.map((item) => {
                item.isChecked = false;
                if (item.id === payload) {
                    item.isChecked = true;
                }
                return {
                    ...item,
                };
            });
        },
        clearDatePostToggle: (state) => {
            state?.datePost?.map((item) => {
                item.isChecked = false;
                return {
                    ...item,
                };
            });
        },
        experienceLavelCheck: (state, { payload }) => {
            state?.experienceLavel?.map((item) => {
                if (item.id === payload) {
                    if (item.isChecked) {
                        item.isChecked = false;
                    } else {
                        item.isChecked = true;
                    }
                }
                return {
                    ...item,
                };
            });
        },
        clearExperienceToggle: (state) => {
            state?.experienceLavel?.map((item) => {
                item.isChecked = false;
                return {
                    ...item,
                };
            });
        },
    },
});

export const {
    addLatestJob,
    clearJobTypeToggle,
    jobTypeCheck,
    datePostCheck,
    clearDatePostToggle,
    experienceLavelCheck,
    clearExperienceToggle,
} = jobSlice.actions;
export default jobSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

this is kinda wierd way to do the search, normally you create query and pass filters using params to recive filtered results. However back to original question "How to pur external api data in redux":

The most simple way, is by using Redux Toolkit Query.

#### 1. define api slice:

```js
// ./src/store/api.js

export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "https://example.com/api" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    category: builder.query({
      query: () => '/category',
    }),
  }),
})

export const { useCategoryQuery } = api
```

#### 2. add it to store:

```js
// ./src/store/store.js

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
    // your slices ...
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(pokemonApi.middleware),
})
```

#### 3. Add to wrapper component

```js
export MySearchLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const {data, isLoading, isFetching} = useCategoryQuery();

  return <>{children}</>
}
```

#### 4. add an extra reducer to your slice:

```
export const jobSlice = createSlice({
  ...
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      api.endpoints.category.matchFulfilled,
        (state, { payload }) => {
          // the payload is going to be your response
          state.category = payload 
        }
    )
  }, 
})
```

Thats about it...
When `useCategoryQuery` gonna be triggered, if it's success the result of the query going to be copy'd to `state.category`